# Exercise $8$, Section $3.D$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Exercise: Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $T : V \to W$ is a surjective linear
map of $V$ onto $W$. Prove that there is a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that
$T|_U$ is an isomorphism of $U$ onto $W$. (Here $T|_U$ means the function $T$
restricted to $U$. In other words, $T|_U$ is the function whose domain is $U$,
with $T|_U$ defined by $T|_U(u) = Tu$ for every $u \in U$

Proof: Given that $T$ is surjective, we know that dim null $T=0$. Thus, $T$ is injective and is invertible. Using the theorem that every subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ is part of a direct sum equal to $V$, there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V=\text{null }T\oplus U$. Then for $v\in V$ we have that $v=n+u$ where $n\in\text{null }T$ and $u\in U$. Thus, $T(v)=T(u)=T|_U(u)$. Because $T$ is invertible, it follows that $T|_U$ is invertible. Hence, $T|_U$ is an isomorphism from $U$ to $V$.

Is this proof correct?

Edit: Upon the answer by José Carlos Santos, I think I have a correct proof now.

Proof $2$: Given that $V$ is finite dimensional. There exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V=\text{null }T\oplus U$. Then for $v\in V$ we have that $v=n+u$ where $n\in \text{null T}$ and $u\in U$. Thus, $T(v)=T(u)=T|_U(u)$. To show that $T|_U$ is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that $T|_U$ is injective since $T|_U$ is surjective as $T$ is surjective.

Let $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=0$. Because null $T+U$ is a direct sum we know that null $T\cap U=\{0\}$. Thus, $T(v)=0\implies T(n+u)=0\implies u=0$ as $u\ne -n$ because null $T$ is a subspace of $V$ and it must be closed under scalar multiplication and we have that null $T\cap U=\{0\}$. Because $T(v)=T(u)$, we have that null $T|_U=\{0\}$.

Hence, $T|_U$ is injective and is an isomorphism from $V$ to $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You claim that, since $T$ is surjective, $\dim\operatorname{null}T=0$. That is false. Consider, for instance, $T\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $T(x,y)=x$. It is surjective, but $(0,1)\in\operatorname{null}T$, and therefore $\dim\operatorname{null}T>0$.

However, it is correct that if you take a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V=U\bigoplus\operatorname{null}T$, then $T|_U$ is an isomorphism between $U$ and $W$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I confused rank nullity while attempting to prove it. Thanks!